# Specifying the return value for xUnit Theory tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

Is it possible to specify the return value for a theory case? Like I have the test methode:

```cs
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestCases))]
public async Task<bool> Test(int i, double d, string str)
{
    return DoStuffAsync(i, d, str);
}
```

and the methode

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestCases()
{
    yield return new object[] { 1, Math.PI, "case1", true };
    yield return new object[] { 2, Math.E,  "case2", false };
}
```

to produce the test cases.

But if I try to run these test cases, I get the error

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The test method expected 3 parameter values, but 4 parameter values were provided.
```

Comment: You just need to add a fourth parameter something like `bool expected value` and compare the output to the value of this parameter in the Assert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite your test a little bit, by adding the parameter for expected result and compare it in `Assert` with value, returned from `DoStuffAsync` method. Also don't forget to change the return value for test method from `Task<bool>` to just `Task` or `async void`, since you are checking the return value inside test and return nothing

```cs
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestCases))]
public async Task Test(int i, double d, string str, bool expected)
{
    var result = await DoStuffAsync(i, d, str);
    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify a return value to a theory test case, but you can add a parameter which acts like an expected value, and compare the test output to this value. In this case, the test would look like this:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestCases))]
public async Task Test(int i, double d, string str, bool expectedValue)
{
     bool actualValue = DoStuffAsync(i, d, str);
     Assert.True(actualValue == expectedValue);
}
```

This will tell the framework if the expected value is equal to the actual value produced by the DoStuffAsync method. The Assert statement is used to evaluate if the test passed or failed.

Yet another, probably much easily maintainable approach is to split one test into two. In the first one, you can expect the method output to be true for each case, and in the second you can expect the output to be false for each case.

First test should look like this

```
[MemberData(nameof(TestCasesTrue))]
public async Task TestTrue(int i, double d, string str)
{
     bool actualValue = DoStuffAsync(i, d, str);
     Assert.Equal(true, actualValue);
}
```

And the second test like this:

```
[MemberData(nameof(TestCasesFalse))]
public async Task TestFalse(int i, double d, string str)
{
     bool actualValue = DoStuffAsync(i, d, str);
     Assert.Equal(false, actualValue);
}
```

Comment: The return type should be `void` for a non-async method, or `Task` for an async method. `Task<T>` serves no value.

Comment: `Assert.True` accepts only single argument, `Assert.Equal` should be instead

Comment: Using `Assert.True(a == b)` is much less readable, and gives a harder-to-interpret assertion message, than `Assert.Equals(a, b)`. In the second case, it would say that it expected `true` but got `false`, even though the test case is testing that the value is `false`. Using `Equals` would give a clearer message of something like "Expected false but got true".

Comment: @MartinCostello That's not entirely true, as `Assert.True(a==b)` just checks if the condition you write into it evaluates to true. The benefit of `Assert.True(a==b)` is that you can add a message, that is shown when the test fails like this `Assert.True(a==b,"Test failed")` which us very usefull if you have multiple Assert statements.

Comment: You can add a message, but I still find it better to use Equals _and_ have a message, in my experience. Plus you have one data-driven test in the Equals scenario, not two _almost_ identical tests, so there's less to maintain.

Comment: @MartinCostello yes, there are many ways to solve a problem, with each one having different pros and cons. However, as per this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/350) you can't have an equals statement with a message.

Comment: Maybe I've missed that as I use Shouldly rather than xunit's native asserts, but I still find `Equals(a, b)` better than `True(a == b)`